# Problem Implelemting MVVM Pattern for an application

Tags: wpf, frameworks, mvvm

First to tell you i am really new to `WPF`

I have some Question for which i have not found ne answers on the web ..... Some Tutorials are there but again they are just confusing.....

Questions :

1) Can `MVVM` Used fro Time Bound Projects (Early Delivery).
2)How should i make my Object `Model` (Entity Classes).
3) Where will be the data access layer. In the Model??...
4) Is the business logic (Some Part) is in `VIEW MODEL`
5)Most Confusing of all----- How many `VIEW MODELS` Do i have to make.....I have seen some sample application On the web ....Either they Finish in 1 View Model or they use 1-2 more VIEW Models than there Entity Classes....

Should i use a framework for implementing for the beginner level...please suggest me some....
Not just me but many of my colleagues are also faceing same issues...

Comment: For framework, check out Caliburn Micro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way that I understand MVVM is this:

1) Your UI is data-bound to your ViewModel.  Your ViewModel in turn wraps your model, and converts it into a binding-friendly interface.  Models might be persistence friendly, but persistence friendly models are not always UI friendly.  The idea of the ViewModel is to bridge that gap and adapt the Model to something the UI can easily bind to.

2) Your model can be any class- entity framework if you prefer, or plain classes (my preference).  The only important thing is that it be able to notify your ViewModel when it's properties change.  So I usually recommend that the model class either implement INotifyPropertyChanged or something similar.

3) This is a design decision, up to you.  Your data access layer should be separate from the Model, but should interact with the Model.  See Single Responsibility Principle.  Your Model only stores data.

4) Business logic can be in the ViewModel, yes, or in controllers that coordinate one or more ViewModels.

5) You typically want to create one ViewModel per type of UI element.  This can get pretty fine-grained, especially when ViewModels contain other ViewModels.  For instance, if you have a grid in your UI, you might have a ViewModel for the whole grid and then another ViewModel class for the rows themselves.  It isn't unusual to have more ViewModels than Models- for instance, you might have a ViewModel for a grid row, and a different ViewModel for a Details view, but they might map to the same Model.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks of the explainations.... i'll surely use these recommendations for my test app.... i am learing MVVM